# Position list item in two rows

Tags: css

I'm trying to get my list in the following structure

```
 -- 48           -- l
 -- 50           -- xl
 -- 52
```

But its displayed like this on my site

```
 -- 48           -- 50
 -- 52           -- l
 -- xl
```

Here is a [Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xdo4owk0/) for more clearence, can anybody figure out what i'm doing wrong?

**Edit**

Here is how the list is generated, as requested

```
<?php foreach ($this->getItems() as $_item): ?>
    <?php if($_item->getName() == "Maat" || $_item->getName() == "maat"): ?>
        <li <?php if(is_numeric($_item->getLabel())):?> class="number"<?php else:?>class="no-number"<?php endif; ?> >
    <?php else: ?>
        <li>
    <?php  endif; ?>
    <?php if ($_item->getCount() > 0): ?>
        <?php $id= $_item->getValue();?>
        <?php $category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($id) ?>

        <?php if($_item->getName() == "Categorie"): ?>
          <div class="checkdiv" id="checkdiv<?php echo $_item->getValue() ?>" onclick="setLocation('<?php echo $this->urlEscape($category->getUrl()) ?>')">
            <input type="checkbox" id="<?php echo $_item->getValue() ?>">
        </div>
        <?php else: ?>
        <div class="checkdiv" id="checkdiv<?php echo $_item->getValue() ?>" onclick="setLocation('<?php echo $this->urlEscape($_item->getUrl()) ?>')">
            <input type="checkbox" id="<?php echo $_item->getValue() ?>">
        </div>
        <?php endif;?>
        <span class="labelholder">
            <?php if($_item->getName() == "Kleur"): ?>
                <?php 
                    $kleur = strtolower($_item->getLabel()); 
                    $kleur = str_replace('-', '', $kleur);
                    $kleur = str_replace(' ', '', $kleur);
                ?>
            <img src="<?php echo $this->getSkinUrl('images/kleuren/'.$kleur.'.png') ?>" id="kleur_img" />
            <?php endif;?>
            <label for="<?php echo $_item->getValue() ?>"><?php echo $_item->getLabel() ?></label>
                <?php if ($this->shouldDisplayProductCount()): ?>
                <span class="count"><?php echo $_item->getCount() ?></span>
        </span>
        <?php endif; ?>
    <?php else: ?>
        <span>
            <?php echo $_item->getLabel(); ?>
            <?php if ($this->shouldDisplayProductCount()): ?>
                <span class="count"><?php echo $_item->getCount() ?></span>
            <?php endif; ?>
        </span>
    <?php endif; ?>
</li>
<?php endforeach ?>
```

In this code snippet all the Magento Store attributes are fetched and displayed in the front-end in the layered navigation

Comment: you are doing nothing wrong but you **forgot** html doesn't go vertical downwards and create columns for you.

Comment: you are doing nothing wrong... that's how lists structure. you could either do 2 lists that are next to each other (in a table or divs), or you can simply reorder your list.

Comment: @starvator what an coincidence, you me saying the same thing :D. You can try limiting a wrapper's height and use CSS3 to specify 2 columns

Comment: @DanielCheung great minds think alike!

Comment: Do you have a rule on how the items are ordered? So we may think of something else for your problem?

Comment: @DanielCheung i've edited my question to show it

Comment: @user3164891 Sorry, I meant why do you split them into 2 columns? Are there any reasons?

Comment: @DanielCheung The client wishes to order it like this

Comment: @user3164891 3 items a column? or evenly distribute between 2 columns?

Comment: @DanielCheung no there isn't a rule like that. He just wants the sizes 36 to 52 on the right side and size s to 4xl to be on the left side

Comment: @user3164891 so numbers on the left and letters on the right? as in your example?

Comment: @DanielCheung indeed

Comment: @user3164891 Why don't you say so in the beginning? :D

Comment: @user3164891 are you fine using jquery?

Comment: @DanielCheung yes, that is no problem

Comment: @user3164891 please see my new answer below :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### New answer: Actually solving the problem: http://jsfiddle.net/vimxts/xdo4owk0/4/

Added:

### JQuery:

```
$(function(){
    $(".number").appendTo(".number-list");
    $(".no-number").appendTo(".no-number-list");
    $(".hidden").remove();
})
```

Easily solved problem by js:

1. Copy `.number` to number list
2. Copy `.no-number` to no-number list
3. Delete PHP generated list (please add class `.hidden` to wrapper before hand)

I removed a few classes styling and added some new ones.

Answer (score 1):

### <strike>Fix(hack): http://jsfiddle.net/vimxts/xdo4owk0/1/</strike>

***Please see new answer below***

```
.wrapper {
    height:300px;
    -webkit-column-count: 2; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    -moz-column-count: 2; /* Firefox */
    column-count: 2;
}
```

Adding a wrapper of **custom** height(restraining how the items place themselves) then specified the column numbers **manually**.

Also displaying blocks on the `<li>`s.

### Here's a snippet:

```css
.wrapper {
    height:300px;
    -webkit-column-count: 2; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    -moz-column-count: 2; /* Firefox */
    column-count: 2;
}

li{list-style:none;display:block;}
li {
margin-bottom: 10px;
margin-left: 20px;
}
.checkdiv {
display: block;
width: 12px;
height: 12px;
float: left;
background-color: #FFF;
border: 1px solid #b5b5b5;
border-radius: 3px;
}
.checkdiv input {
display: none;
}

.labelholder {
margin: 10px;
color: #4c4c4c;
}

label {
display: inline-block;
font-size: 13px;
font-family: "Raleway", "Helvetica Neue", Verdana, Arial, sans-serif;
font-weight: 600;
-moz-user-select: none;
-ms-user-select: none;
-webkit-user-select: none;
-o-user-select: none;
user-select: none;
}

.number {
width: 40%;
float: left;
}

.no-number {
float: left;
width: 40%;
clear: right;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
<li class="number">
    <div class="checkdiv" id="checkdiv61">
        <input type="checkbox" id="61"/>
    </div> 
    <span class="labelholder">
        <label for="61">48</label>
        <span class="count">2</span>
    </span>
</li>

<li class="number">
    <div class="checkdiv" id="checkdiv60">
        <input type="checkbox" id="60"/>
    </div> 
    <span class="labelholder">
        <label for="60">50</label>
        <span class="count">2</span>
    </span>
</li>

<li class="no-number">
    <div class="checkdiv" id="checkdiv59">
        <input type="checkbox" id="59"/>
    </div> 
    <span class="labelholder">
        <label for="59">52</label>
        <span class="count">3</span>
    </span>
</li>

<li class="number">
    <div class="checkdiv" id="checkdiv58">
        <input type="checkbox" id="58"/>
    </div> 
    <span class="labelholder">
        <label for="58">xl</label>
        <span class="count">2</span>
    </span>
</li>

<li class="no-number">
    <div class="checkdiv" id="checkdiv57">
        <input type="checkbox" id="57"/>
    </div> 
    <span class="labelholder">
        <label for="57">l</label>
        <span class="count">2</span>
    </span>
</li>
</div>
```

Comment: please see my new answer below, you can even interpret that in php instead of using my js

Answer (score -1):

try this code :)

```
<li class="number">
    <div class="checkdiv" id="checkdiv61">
        <input type="checkbox" id="61"/>
    </div> 
    <span class="labelholder">
        <label for="61">48</label>
        <span class="count">2</span>
    </span>
</li>

<li class="no-number">
    <div class="checkdiv" id="checkdiv57">
        <input type="checkbox" id="57"/>
    </div> 
    <span class="labelholder">
        <label for="57">l</label>
        <span class="count">2</span>
    </span>
</li>

<li class="number">
    <div class="checkdiv" id="checkdiv60">
        <input type="checkbox" id="60"/>
    </div> 
    <span class="labelholder">
        <label for="60">50</label>
        <span class="count">2</span>
    </span>
</li>

<li class="number">
    <div class="checkdiv" id="checkdiv58">
        <input type="checkbox" id="58"/>
    </div> 
    <span class="labelholder">
        <label for="58">xl</label>
        <span class="count">2</span>
    </span>
</li>

<li class="no-number">
    <div class="checkdiv" id="checkdiv59">
        <input type="checkbox" id="59"/>
    </div> 
    <span class="labelholder">
        <label for="59">52</label>
        <span class="count">3</span>
    </span>
</li>
```

Comment: you did actually nothing on the css?

Comment: Changing the elements order is not an option cause the list is generated by php